# How to use a condition on a whole data.frame with a vector as comparison?

Tags: r, dataframe

This might be quite simple but it's been bugging me for a while.
I lack the terminology for this type of indexing/conditional check - so it was hard for me to look it up.

Have a data frame dat.

```
X1 X2 X3
1   1  2
1   1  3
3   1  2
```

`dat == 1` gives me:

```
 X1    X2    X3
TRUE  TRUE FALSE
TRUE  TRUE FALSE
FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

`dat == 1 | dat == 3` gives me:

```
 X1   X2   X3
TRUE TRUE FALSE
TRUE TRUE TRUE
TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

However, `dat %in% c(1,3)` gives me a single line vector back, and doesn't work "as intended". How can I get it to work on a vector without some fancy loop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All these commands should give you vectors back. The output that you copied and pasted are respectively the results of commands `dat == 1` and `dat == 1 | dat == 3`. Try to execute the command `dat %in% c(1,3)`.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I should rephrase, if I have a vector of values, I do not want to be doing dat[dat == 1 | dat ==2 | dat == 3 | dat ==4] and so on. I thought that doing dat[dat %in% c(1,2,3,4)] would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot you're right, I made a mistake. I have corrected my question above to reflect it. `dat %in% c(1,3)` does not give me the 'desired' output, which I would like it to be the same as `dat == 1 | dat == 3`

Comment: Try `sapply(dat, function(x) x %in% c(1, 3))`, may throw it into an answer below shortly.

Comment: If the goal is to do something like `dat[dat %in% c(1,2,3,4)]`, then `unlist(dat)[unlist(dat) %in% 1:4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply(dat, 1, function(x) x %in% c(1,3))

     [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Or `purrr::map_df(dat, ~.x %in% c(1,3))` if you like a `purrr` solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's answer with a full reprex and some further explanation.

Create the data.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(1, 1, 3),
  x2 = c(1, 1, 1),
  x3 = c(2, 3, 2)
)
```

As with other answers, using the apply family works.

```
sapply(dat, function(x) x %in% c(1, 3))
#       x1   x2    x3
# [1,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

The reason `%in%` does not work as you might expect can be found in the documentation, which states.

```
"Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors,
and then x and table are coerced to a common type"
```

We can check this with our reprex.

```
as.character(dat)
# [1] "c(1, 1, 3)" "c(1, 1, 1)" "c(2, 3, 2)"

as.character(dat) %in% c("c(1, 1, 3)")
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Which gives the same as

```
dat %in% c("c(1, 1, 3)")
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```